# If E' is the set of all limit points of a set E what does (E')' represent?

Tags: notation

The answer to this question is sure to make me feel embarrassed, but here we go:

I am wondering about notation if $E'$ is the set of limit points of a set E, then what does $\left(E'\right)'$ mean? The reason I wonder is since the book uses $E^c$ for the complement of E, hence the representation of $\left(\right)'$ must mean something different?

Comment: The set of limit points of the set of limit points of $E$, maybe?

Comment: It's very likely that $(E')'=E'$ since the closure of a set is closed.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM A point in $E'$ may be isolated in $E'$ so not a limit point of $E'$.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Remember that $E'$ is the *derivative* of $E$ (= set of isolated points), not the closure; so there's no reason to expect $E'=E''$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(E')'$ is the set of limit points of limit points of $E$ - and this is in general *not the same* as $E'$.

To see this, first consider the set $X=\{1, {1\over 2}, {1\over 3}, {1\over 4}, ...\}$ - clearly $X'=\{0\}$.

Now for $a, b$ positive real numbers, let ${X\over a}+b=\{{x\over a}+b: x\in X\}$ - this is just the set $X$, compressed by a factor of $a$ and then shifted to the right $b$ units. Note that $({X\over a}+b)'=\{b\}$.

We're going to place a bunch of shrinking copies of $X$ next to each other.

Let:

- $Y_0={X\over 1}+0$ (this is just $X$)
- $Y_1={X\over 2}+1$
- $Y_2={X\over 4}+{3\over 2}$
- $Y_3={X\over 8}+{7\over 4}$

.
.
.

- $Y_n={X\over 2^n}+{2^{n}-1\over 2^{n-1}}$.

Now let $Z=\bigcup Y_n$.

If you draw this, you'll see that $Z'=\{0, 1, {3\over 2}, {7\over 4}, ..., {2^n-1\over 2^{n-1}}, ...\}$. But this set itself has a limit point, namely $2$; so $(Z')'=\{2\}$.

---

We can go further. We can similarly define $E^{(n)}$ for each $n$: set $E^{(0)}=E$, $E^{(n+1)}=(E^{(n)})'$. We can even keep going "past infinity": we can define $E^{(\alpha)}$ for $\alpha$ an [arbitrary ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number), by expanding the definition above to include $E^{(\lambda)}=\bigcap_{\alpha<\lambda}(E^{(\alpha)})$ for $\lambda$ limit. This is called the *Cantor-Bendixson process*.

Let's say we work inside $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology specifically. Then it turns out that for each set $X$, there is some countable ordinal $\alpha$ such that $X^{(\alpha)}=X^{(\alpha+1)}$ (that is, the hierarchy [*stabilizes at some countable stage*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_(mathematics)#Cantor.E2.80.93Bendixson_rank)), but at the same time there are sets (even closed sets!) which take arbitrarily large countable ordinals to stabilize.

One neat application of this is that every closed set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be uniquely written as the disjoint union of a countable set and a perfect (= closed with no isolated points) set. If you're interested in this sort of thing, look up **descriptive set theory**.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare $(E')'$ with $E'$.

> **Claim**: In general, it's neither true that $(E')' \subset E'$ nor that $E' \subset (E')'$.

Here's a somehow satisfying argument for the first claim:

Let $x \in (E')'$. Let $n \in N(x)$. We know that $n \cap (E' -\{x\}) \neq \varnothing$, so $\exists y \in n \cap E'$ such that $y\neq x$. As $y \in n$, $n \in N(y)$, so as $y \in E'$, $n \cap (E - \{y\}) \neq \varnothing$, i.e. $\exists z \in n\cap E$ with $z \neq y$. Notice that this doesn't lead to the desired result (which is $x \in E'$). Though, if the space is $T_1$, then we could've consider $n-\{x\}$ as a neighborhood of $y$, and adjusting the above argument we get a $z \in (n-\{x\}) \cap (E-\{y\})$, so we are done because $ (n-\{x\}) \cap (E-\{y\}) \subset n \cap (E-\{x\})$.

So, in general, $(E')' \not \subset E'$ unless the space is $T_1$.

For the other way around, consider $X = \{0,1,2\}$, $\tau = \{\varnothing, \{1,2\},X\}$. For $E = \{0,1\}$, $E' = \{0\}$, and $E'' = \varnothing$.

Comment: Note that there are even *nice* spaces for which $E'\not\subseteq E''$ - e.g. this happens in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.